# how to update single value for multiple ids in Hql.?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, hql

String sql = "UPDATE table SET `enabled`= true";
sql += " WHERE m_id=" + mId + " AND id IN (:Id)";
where Ids is string consist of multiple values with comma separated.
I am trying in HQl like this

**HQL Query**

```
String stringQuery = "UPDATE table SET `enable`=:ENABLED
       WHERE m_id=:M_ID AND id IN (:Id)";
       TypedQuery<String> query = session.createSQLQuery(stringQuery);
       query.setParameter("ENABLED", true);
       query.setParameter("M_ID", mId);
       query.setParameter("ID", Ids);
       query.executeUpdate();
```

**Entity**

```
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "table")
    public class Table implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID   = 1L;
    
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Integer id;
        @Column(name = "m_id")
        private Integer MId;
     @Column(name = "enabled")
        private Boolean enabled;
    }
```

but i am facing javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

Comment: Show me your `Entity`

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej entity class